# TABULAOTR, Total calculation of table is not downloading

Tags: javascript, printing, tabulator

**Sorry** for my English, as I am Russian :)I use Tabulator. Why is the table footer not printed? And I can’t get the data from the footer. And the footer doesn’t print, I don’t know what it is connected with.
[colsole log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9g7I.png) ,
[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiDMQ.png)

```
var table = new Tabulator("#uchet-table", {
layout:"fitColumns",
    movableRows:false,
    movableColumns: true,
    downloadConfig:{
        columnCalcs:true, 
    },
    groupBy:["object"],
    tooltips : true,   // Подсказки при наведении на ячейку
    columnCalcs:"both",
    groupClosedShowCalcs:true,
    groupToggleElement:"arrow", //arrow, header, false
    placeholder:"Нет данных",
    persistence:{
      sort:false,
      filter:false,
      columns:false,
    },
    persistenceID:"examplePerststance",
    groupStartOpen:true,
    columns:[
        {title:" ", field:"idact", sorter:"number", width:30},
        {title:"Месяц", field:"mouth", sorter:"string"},
        {title:"Объект", field:"object", sorter:"string"},
        {title:"Акт/Номер", field:"nomer_acta", sorter:"string",
        bottomCalc:function(values,data,calcParams){
          console.log(data);
          return "Итого:";
        }
        },
        {title:"Сумма без НДС", field:"sum_s_koef",  formatter:"money", width:180, align:"center", bottomCalc:"sum", formatterParams:paramMoney,
        bottomCalcParams:{precision: 2}, 
        bottomCalcFormatter: "money",
        bottomCalcFormatterParams:paramMoney,
        },
        {title:"НДС 20 %", field:"nds", formatter:"nds", width:180, align:"center", bottomCalc:"sum", formatterParams:paramMoney, 
        bottomCalcParams:{precision: 2}, 
        bottomCalcFormatter: "money",
        bottomCalcFormatterParams:paramMoney,
        },
        {title:"Всего с НДС", field:"sum_s_nds", formatter:"money", width:180, align:"center", bottomCalc:"sum", formatterParams:paramMoney,
        bottomCalcParams:{precision: 2}, 
        bottomCalcFormatter: "money",
        bottomCalcFormatterParams:paramMoney,
        },
    ],
    printAsHtml:true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The print system was overhauled in the 4.6 release back in march 2020, try updating your version of the library and it should print just fine